# Reading files in order in BASH script

Tags: bash, sorting, file, grep

So I've got a bash script that greps a series of subdirectories, looking for files that contain a certain string, and then printing file totals and directory totals for the string's occurences. The code is as follows.

```
  for dir in $(find * -type d); do
  echo "directory: $dir" >> $OUT
  for f in $(find $dir/* -type f); do
    echo -n "$(basename $f) " >> $OUT
    grep -c -h $1 $f >> $OUT
  done
  echo -n "directory total: " >> $OUT
  grep -c -h $1 $dir/*.* | awk '{SUM += $1} END {print SUM}' >> $OUT
  done
```

When it does this, if I read in 10 files, it lists them in the text file as **file1.txt, file10.txt, file2.txt** etc...

Is there any way I could make it print file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt etc and have the 10th file be actually listed in order?

I'm new to BASH so I was just wondering if any knew anything about this. Any help greatly appreciated. And yes, the files are literally named file1.txt, file2.txt etc. This is mostly just to familiarize myself with BASH scripting.

Comment: I usually name files `file01.txt`, `file02.txt`, ... `file99.txt` for this reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find -type d | while read -r dir
do
    echo "directory: $dir"
    find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort --version-sort | while read -r f
    do
        echo -n "$(basename "$f") "
        grep -c -h "$1" "$f"
    done
    grep -c -h "$1" "$dir/*" | awk -F: '{SUM += $1} END {print "directory total:", SUM}'
done > "$OUT"
```

- Move the redirection to the end of the loop
- Use `while read` instead of `for` in case filenames include spaces (additional measures can be taken to protect against some less common odd characters if needed)
- Quote your variables also to protect white space
- Use `-maxdepth 1` with the inner `find` to avoid overlapping duplication
- Use `sort --version-sort` to get the filenames in the order you want
- AWK can print the text at the same time it prints the total
- The field separator needs to be set to a colon
- Instead of `echo -n "$(basename "$f") "` you could use `echo -n "${f##*/} "`

Answer (score 0):

The files are sorted lexicographically (that's why file10 goes after file1). If files are named `file<num>`, it's easier - you use `sort -k1.5n` on them. In general case it's trickier - there will be some parsing involved, tell if your case is general:)

Some points:

Probably you need not `find $dir/* -type f` but `find $dir -type f`. In former case you use globbing feature of the shell. What about subdirectories?

Btw, you can rewrite it as following to skip spamming every line with `>> $OUT`:

```
for dir in $(find * -type d); do
  echo "directory: $dir"
  for f in $(find $dir/* -type f); do
    echo -n "$(basename $f) "
    grep -c -h $1 $f
  done
  echo -n "directory total: "
  grep -c -h $1 $dir/*.* | awk '{SUM += $1} END {print SUM}'
done >> $OUT
```

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
for f in $(find $dir/* -type f); do
```

to this line:

```
for f in $(find $dir/* -type f | sort --numeric-sort); do
```

Comment: I believe numeric-sort won't help, as the beginning of the key isn't numerical.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I figured it out with the help of you guys and some tinkering around. Not sure if this is the best way but I ended up with this working...

```
for f in $(find $dir -type f | cut -d. -f1 | cut -d'e' -f3 | sort -n); do
    echo -n "  file$(basename $f).txt: "
    grep -c -h $1 $dir/"file$f"'.txt'
  done
```

Obviously this is very specific to the filenames I had, but it was a good thing to learn more about. Thanks